# Chinese and japanese language not supported in IE?

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, utf-8, internet-explorer-8

I am doing the **chat** project in `java` with `spring 3.2`.

My `chat` functionality works fine .But I am having the problem with the `multi-language` support in **IE**.

There is a problem with the **Chinese and japanese language** chat in **IE**.

The chinese and japanese language works fine in other browsers but not in *IE*.I ma using the **IE8**.

Hope our stack users will give  a good solution.

Comment: Did you try to download this MultiLanguage package? [**IEMULTILANGUAGE**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9769)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the **Solution** by adding the below **css**,

```
font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```